# C++ What If The Conditional Operator Were Left Associative

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

This is a question I found that I don't really know the answer. Suppose we have the following code:

```
int grade = 100;
string finalgrade = (grade > 90) ? "High Pass"
                                 : (grade > 75) ? "Pass"
                                                : (grade >= 60) ? "low pass" : "fail";
```

How would the conditional operator be evaluated if it were left associative?

Comment: Basically, you would have PHP. Hahahaha, I wish I was joking. See http://phpsadness.com/sad/30

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask what would happen if a language rule was changed. The people who change it would write what happens in the new law, we would read it, learn it and apply it. Once of the things we'd keep doing, however, would be avoiding complex expressions like the one you posted.

Comment: @DanielDaranas It can make sense to ask what would happen.  Imagine if the PHP language author pondered what the impact would be.

Comment: Just a nit, but the sequence of `...?...:...?...:...` corresponds exactly the the `if ... else if ... else if ....` situation, and should be formatted in the same way, without the additional indents for the second, third, etc.  In such cases, I'll add a new line before each `?`, and indent all the same, but other solutions are viable, as long as they don't keep indenting further each time you add a `?`.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Arguably true, but sometimes it can help understand why the current rule is "like this" and not "like that", and having a kind of rationale can help remember the rule! :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I found this question in the book I'm reading, but couldn't figure out the answer because it seems so senseless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `?:` were left-associative, that would mean that:

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

would be equivalent to:

```
(a ? b : c) ? d : e
```

instead of:

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

Applying this to your example, you'd get:

```
string finalgrade =   (  (  (grade > 90)
                          ? "High Pass"
                          : (grade > 75))
                       ? "Pass"
                       : (grade >= 60))
                    ? "low pass"
                    : "fail";
```

which---assuming that the compiler didn't complain about the mismatched types---for `grade = 100` would result in:

```
string finalgrade =   (  (  true
                          ? "High Pass"
                          : (grade > 75))
                       ? "Pass"
                       : (grade >= 60))
                    ? "low pass"
                    : "fail";

string finalgrade =   (  "High Pass"
                       ? "Pass"
                       : (grade >= 60))
                    ? "low pass"
                    : "fail";

string finalgrade =   "Pass"
                    ? "low pass"
                    : "fail";

string finalgrade = "low pass";
```

Comment: The results would be more interesting than that, because the compiler will try to unify the types on either side of the `:`.  There's a `bool` on one side, and a `char const*` on the other.  A `char const*` can be converted to a `bool`, but not the inverse, so you'd end up trying to initialize `finalgrade` with a `bool` (which won't compile).

Comment: And to be very clear: `grade > 90` does _not_ evaluate to `1`, it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I did note that this is assuming that the compiler wouldn't be complaining about the mismatched types (which it would, but this is a hypothetical exercise anyway).  However, I don't see how it'd ever try to initialize `finalgrade` with a `bool` value since the only two possible outcomes in this exercise would be `"low pass"` and `"fail"`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oops, I forgot that this was a C++ question and not C.  I've corrected the `true` bit.

Comment: Given `a ? b : c`, the compiler will try to find a common type for `b` and `c`.  In C, it will clearly fail, as the result of `>` is an `int`, a string literal decays to `char*`, and there are no implicit conversions between these two types.  In C++, the result of `>` is `bool`, and there _is_ an implicit conversion of a pointer to `bool` (but not the reverse).  On further reading of the standard, however, not all implicit conversions are considered; in particular, the conversion of pointer to `bool` will not be used, so the results will also be illegal.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  I'm not claiming that it's legal.  But it's a thought exercise anyway, so while we're pretending that `?:` is left-associative, we might as well also pretend that C++ did consider the necessary conversions to unify the then/else expressions.

Answer (score 0):

in your example : 
finalgrade = "High Pass"

the computations are done from right to left

Comment: "How _would_ the conditional operator be evaluated _if it were **left** associative_?"

Comment: right, sorry, I misread :) my answer is useless (but accurate)